# Convert x-axis day into month with plotly in R

Tags: r, plotly

I have data obtained on a daily basis and have been plotting it with plotly using this code:

```
library(plotly)
library(lubridate)
library(raster)

dates <- seq(ymd('2010-01-01'), ymd('2020-01-01'), by = 'day')
dat <- data.frame(Day = yday(dates), Year = year(dates), Val = rnorm(length(dates)))
mat <- as.matrix(rasterFromXYZ(dat))
rownames(mat) <- unique(dat$Year)
y <- as.numeric(rownames(mat))

plot_ly(z = mat,y = y, type = "surface", colorscale = list(thresholds_colors = seq(0, 1, length = 6),
                   colors = c('gray','blue','skyblue','green','yellow','red')),
        showscale=TRUE) %>%
        layout(title = list(text = 'Test Plot',x=0.47, y=0.92),
         scene=list(
           yaxis=list(title='Year'),
           zaxis = list(title = 'Value'),
           xaxis = list(title = 'Julian day',autorange="reversed"),
           camera = list(eye = list(x = 1.3, y = 1.3, z = 1.5))))
```

And the plot looks like this.

[image]

How can I convert the x-axis containing the "Julian day" into months so that the ticks would show 'Jan', 'Feb', etc. I tried to do something similar between the row names and column names by doing

```
colnames(mat) <- month.abb[month(as.Date(0:365,origin='2000-01-01'))]
x <- colnames(mat)

plot_ly(z = mat, y = y, x = x, ...
```

This works in naming the axis correctly but it reduces the resolution of the data since it seems to only be selecting one value from each month.

**Updated Code**

```
library(plotly)
library(lubridate)
library(raster)

dates <- seq(ymd('2010-01-01'), ymd('2020-01-01'), by = 'day')
dat <- data.frame(Day = yday(dates), Year = year(dates), Val = rnorm(length(dates)))
mat <- as.matrix(rasterFromXYZ(dat))
rownames(mat) <- unique(dat$Year)
y <- as.numeric(rownames(mat))

curTcks <- round(seq(1, 366, by = 30.5))
pCurT <- parse_date_time(curTcks, orders = "j") %>% 
  month() 
newTckTxt <- month.abb[pCurT]


plot_ly(z = mat, y = y, type = "surface", 
        colorscale = list(thresholds_colors = seq(0, 1, length = 6),
                          colors = c('gray','blue','skyblue','green',
                                           'yellow','red')),
                                           showscale=TRUE) %>%
  layout(title = list(text = 'Test Plot',x=0.47, y=0.92),
         scene=list(
           yaxis=list(title='Year'),
           zaxis = list(title = 'Value'),
           xaxis = list(title = 'Julian day', autorange="reversed",
                        tickvals = seq(1, 366, by = 30.5),
                        ticktext = newTckTxt),
           camera = list(eye = list(x = 1.3, y = 1.3, z = 1.5))))
```

Comment: I'd suggest picking an arbitrary year (perhaps a leap year to capture Feb 29) and adding `Julian day - 1` to that year's Jan 1.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? I did add a leap year to try name the matrix columns and it does name them correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to change the data; you could just change the tick labels.

Using the current ticks as the baseline:

```
curTcks <- c(1, seq(50, 350, by = 50)) # there's no month zero
```

Next, parse the dates back to calendar dates; then extract the months.

```
pCurT <- parse_date_time(curTcks, orders = "j") %>% 
  month()
```

Now collect the labels for the months that you extracted.

```
newTckTxt <- month.abb[pCurT]
```

Now you can add this to the `scene` for the `xaxis`.

```
xaxis = list(title = 'Julian day', autorange="reversed",
             tickvals = seq(0, 350, by = 50),
             ticktext = newTckTxt)
```

[image]

##### Here's the code all of the code combined.

```
# get months from jdates considering current tick labels
curTcks <- c(1, seq(50, 350, by = 50))
pCurT <- parse_date_time(curTcks, orders = "j") %>% 
  month() 
newTckTxt <- month.abb[pCurT]


plot_ly(z = mat, y = y, type = "surface", 
        colorscale = list(thresholds_colors = seq(0, 1, length = 6),
                          colors = c('gray','blue','skyblue','green',
                                     'yellow','red')),
        showscale=TRUE) %>%
  layout(title = list(text = 'Test Plot',x=0.47, y=0.92),
         scene=list(
           yaxis=list(title='Year'),
           zaxis = list(title = 'Value'),
           xaxis = list(title = 'Julian day', autorange="reversed",
                        tickvals = seq(0, 350, by = 50),
                        ticktext = newTckTxt),
           camera = list(eye = list(x = 1.3, y = 1.3, z = 1.5))))
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked very well. I wasn't liking that the tick marks don't actually line up with the beginning of the month making the axis feel a little misleading. I've updated my code to get the month tick to be close to the beginning of each month.